# How to join two tables?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

[Feedback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd9ob.png)

[User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB7e8.png)

This query works.Fetching datas in feedback table:

```
    public function feedback_data()
    {
        $recipe_id = 0;
        $this->db->where('recipe_id',$recipe_id);
        $query = $this->db->get('feedback');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

I need to fetch feedback_id and comment from feedback table and firstname and lastname from user table where user_id from feedback is equal to user_id from user. By the way, here's my query and i think it's not working.

```
$this->db->select('f.feedback_id, f.comment, f.recipe_id, f.user_id as Fid'.'u.firstname, u.lastname, u.user_id as Uid');
    $this->db->from('feedback f')
    $this->db->join('user u','u.user_id = f.user_id');
    $this->db->where('f.recipe_id', $recipe_id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $query;
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? Also this has typos eg `$recpe_id` so please cut and paste your actual query. Please type those links inline. What SQL are you using? Please read about MVCEs in the help links. PS You want `u.user_id = f.user_id`.

Comment: I'm using mysql.. should i remove all the aliases?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? What is the correct query?

Comment: What is the '.' in your SELECT? Please per my comment cut and paste all code.

Comment: There are no columns called `Uid`. That is a column alias. [Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: I suggest you to print your last query and execute it in sql to see if anything wrong with query. Use `echo 4this->db->last_query()` to print last query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$this->db->select('f.feedback_id, f.comment, f.recipe_id, f.user_id as Fid'.'u.firstname, u.lastname, u.user_id as Uid');
$this->db->from('feedback f')
$this->db->join('user u','u.user_id = f.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('f.recipe_id', $recipe_id);
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
return $query;
```

Try this if the above code does not work :

```
    $this->db->select('f.feedback_id, f.comment, f.recipe_id, f.user_id as Fid'.'u.firstname, u.lastname, u.user_id as Uid');
    $this->db->from('feedback f');
    $this->db->join('user u','u.user_id = f.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('f.recipe_id', $recipe_id);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```